# How to bring data frame into single column from multiple columns in python

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, database, dataframe

I have data format in these multiple columns. So I want to bring all 4 columns of data into a single column.

```
YEAR Month pcp1 pcp2 pcp3 pcp4              
1984    1   0   0   0   0
1984    2   1.2 0   0   0
1984    3   0   0   0   0
1984    4   0   0   0   0
1984    5   0   0   0   0
1984    6   0   0   0   1.6
1984    7   3   3   9.2 3.2
1984    8   6.2 27.1    5.4 0
1984    9   0   0   0   0
1984    10  0   0   0   0
1984    11  0   0   0   0
1984    12  0   0   0   0
```

Comment: Are there actually 31 columns?

Comment: is your desired output correct?? month values are ranging from 1-31

Comment: What is your expected output dataframe

Answer (score 1):

### [`pd.wide_to_long`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html)

```
pd.wide_to_long(df, i=['YEAR', 'Month'], j='day', stubnames='pcp', suffix='\d+', sep='').reset_index()
```

---

```
    YEAR  Month  day   pcp
0   1984      1    1   0.0
1   1984      1    2   0.0
2   1984      1    3   0.0
3   1984      1    4   0.0
4   1984      2    1   1.2
5   1984      2    2   0.0
6   1984      2    3   0.0
7   1984      2    4   0.0
8   1984      3    1   0.0
9   1984      3    2   0.0
10  1984      3    3   0.0
11  1984      3    4   0.0
12  1984      4    1   0.0
13  1984      4    2   0.0
14  1984      4    3   0.0
15  1984      4    4   0.0
16  1984      5    1   0.0
17  1984      5    2   0.0
18  1984      5    3   0.0
19  1984      5    4   0.0
20  1984      6    1   0.0
21  1984      6    2   0.0
22  1984      6    3   0.0
23  1984      6    4   1.6
24  1984      7    1   3.0
25  1984      7    2   3.0
26  1984      7    3   9.2
27  1984      7    4   3.2
28  1984      8    1   6.2
29  1984      8    2  27.1
30  1984      8    3   5.4
31  1984      8    4   0.0
32  1984      9    1   0.0
33  1984      9    2   0.0
34  1984      9    3   0.0
35  1984      9    4   0.0
36  1984     10    1   0.0
37  1984     10    2   0.0
38  1984     10    3   0.0
39  1984     10    4   0.0
40  1984     11    1   0.0
41  1984     11    2   0.0
42  1984     11    3   0.0
43  1984     11    4   0.0
44  1984     12    1   0.0
45  1984     12    2   0.0
46  1984     12    3   0.0
47  1984     12    4   0.0
```

Comment: Changed ur profile I see ... New shubham :)

Comment: Empty DataFrame
Columns: [YEAR, MN, DRF, DRF30, DRF27, DRF06, DRF04, DRF03, DRF17, DRF10, DRF28, DRF01, DRF18, DRF23, DRF07, DRF13, DRF20, DRF05, DRF24, DRF29, DRF12, DRF15, DRF14, DRF02, DRF21, DRF11, DRF26, DRF25, DRF31, DRF16, DRF22, DRF09, DRF19, DRF08, pcp]
Index: []

Comment: I am getting this error and not getting single column format

Comment: @sammywemmy just new pic but same old me  :-)

Comment: @DebrupaChatterjee Check your column names in real dataframe and use them accordingly in the `wide_to_long` formula.

Answer (score 0):

```
df.melt(id_vars=["YEAR", "Month"], var_name='Date', value_name="pcp").sort_values(['Month','Date']).reset_index(drop=True)
```

```
YEAR    Month   Date    pcp
0   1984    1   pcp1    0.0
1   1984    1   pcp2    0.0
2   1984    1   pcp3    0.0
3   1984    1   pcp4    0.0
4   1984    2   pcp1    1.2
5   1984    2   pcp2    0.0
6   1984    2   pcp3    0.0
7   1984    2   pcp4    0.0
8   1984    3   pcp1    0.0
9   1984    3   pcp2    0.0
10  1984    3   pcp3    0.0
11  1984    3   pcp4    0.0
12  1984    4   pcp1    0.0
13  1984    4   pcp2    0.0
14  1984    4   pcp3    0.0
15  1984    4   pcp4    0.0
16  1984    5   pcp1    0.0
17  1984    5   pcp2    0.0
18  1984    5   pcp3    0.0
19  1984    5   pcp4    0.0
20  1984    6   pcp1    0.0
21  1984    6   pcp2    0.0
22  1984    6   pcp3    0.0
23  1984    6   pcp4    1.6
24  1984    7   pcp1    3.0
25  1984    7   pcp2    3.0
26  1984    7   pcp3    9.2
27  1984    7   pcp4    3.2
28  1984    8   pcp1    6.2
29  1984    8   pcp2    27.1
30  1984    8   pcp3    5.4
31  1984    8   pcp4    0.0
32  1984    9   pcp1    0.0
33  1984    9   pcp2    0.0
34  1984    9   pcp3    0.0
35  1984    9   pcp4    0.0
36  1984    10  pcp1    0.0
37  1984    10  pcp2    0.0
38  1984    10  pcp3    0.0
39  1984    10  pcp4    0.0
40  1984    11  pcp1    0.0
41  1984    11  pcp2    0.0
42  1984    11  pcp3    0.0
43  1984    11  pcp4    0.0
44  1984    12  pcp1    0.0
45  1984    12  pcp2    0.0
46  1984    12  pcp3    0.0
47  1984    12  pcp4    0.0
```

Comment: After running this code I am not getting days data in a serial format so facing an issue with this ...... station_df.melt(id_vars=["Year", "Month"], var_name='Date', value_name="pcp").sort_values(['Year','Month','Date']).reset_index(drop=True)